# Convert Word/PowerPoint XML to docx/pptx

Tags: c#, .net, xml, openxml

I am wondering how I can solve the following issue: I have a presentation whose text I want to replace (classic ctrl+h operation). I see currently two ways to do this:

1. Using [Open XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part): That seems the obvious choice - however in future I might have to do the same operation for Word. Therefore why bother with Open XML and just use XML directly?
2. Using XML: I can save the pptx as Presnentation XML Document and then replace text in the XML.

Now I have one question: After I replace text in my .xml-file - how do I get that back to pptx/docx?

Answer (score 1):

.docx, .xlsx, .pptx etc are all in fact zip files.  If you copy the file and rename it using a .zip extension, you can then unpack the file using your favourite zip application.  You will find that the file consists of a folder structure with many (often very many) xml files.  These files you can edit directly by whatever means you prefer.

All you then need to do is to save the xml file, re-zip the complete structure and rename back to the original format.  The only thing you need to be careful of, is to make sure that you do not alter the xml structure - it can be very unforgiving!

I have used this technique to write my own library for reading and writing xlsx files using just the standard tools that come with .Net (no third party libraries).

Comment: XML structure is unforgiving indeed, even when using OpenXML